# Was Asgard technology ever duplicated on other SGC ships?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-atlantis

In the SG-1 finale "Unending", the Asgard call SG-1 to meet them with the USS Odyssey in order to

> install all of the Asgard's most current technology on the ship before they end their civilization in mass suicide. For the entirety of the episode, it is mentioned several times that the Odyssey is now the sole legacy of the entire Asgard race and must be preserved as such.

Afterwards, however, in Stargate: Atlantis the ship is still routinely going on missions.

**Is there any indication in the extended materials that the technology was successfully duplicated on other Earth ships, or is Odyssey still unique?**

Comment: It doesn't make much sense as a "legacy" if they can't duplicate it to the other ships. They should have an Asgard computer core which should contain info to allow them to replicate it elsewhere, at least in time.

Comment: -1 for gratuitous use of spoiler tag.

Comment: Does an _Odyssey_ which has had all of its components replaced by the Asgard remain fundamentally the same ship?

Comment: @Lexible - lol not at all, the question refers to both shows as well as the franchise as a whole. Therefore all three tags. You'll note that I did NOT include SGU. Or the movie.

Comment: @Tronman - I agree. However, they specifically said in the show that the Asgard computer core was completely integrated with the ship's systems. Hence the question.

Comment: Wasn't the point of Unending that the Asgard technology invariably attracted the Ori?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - not so much "attracted" them... moreso that they were tracking the energy signature of the core to find Odyssey, but that was no longer an issue after the events of "Ark of Truth".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both the Daedalus and Apollo were retro-fit with Asgard plasma beam weapons. iirc the Hammond had all the new Asgard tech built it rather than bolted on, I believe that it was constructed after the Asgard became extinct.

"Be My Sins Remembered" (Stargate Atlantis) has both the Daedalus and Apollo arrive having been retrofitted with Asgard plasma beam weapons.

"The Last Man" (Stargate Atlantis) has the Daedalus firstly take out the hyperdrive of Michael's cruiser, later destroying the cruiser. In that same episode in the "alternate reality" the Phoenix had an Asgard computer core on the bridge, so it's probably a reasonable assumption that the Daedalus, Apollo and Sun Tzu also have Asgard computer cores on board.

> McKAY: Sure, the Apollo and the Daedalus have been retrofitted with the new Asgard plasma beam weapon which – given – are very, very powerful, but they still can't destroy the Replicators.
>
> <sub><sup>[SGA: Be All My Sins Remember'd - Transcript](https://www.gateworld.net/atlantis/s4/be-all-my-sins-rememberd/transcript/)</sup></sub>

Comment: They were using them in multiple episodes. "Be My Sins Remembered" and "Enemy At The Gate" are two that immediately spring to mind. There's also the episode where they rescued Teyla from Michael's hive ship (might have been a cruiser)

Comment: @Valorum will have to wait to get a quote, Amazon Prime is running slow for me atm. A good quote is iirc at the initial briefing in Atlantis during the episode "Be My Sins Remembered"

Comment: @Valorum found a copy of the quote, I forgot that Gateworld has got transcripts of all Stargate episodes from all series

Comment: Much improved and the quote is spot on. Have an upvote and a bounty.

Comment: Works for me - have an upvote and a checkmark! Thanks!